# How to validate form data when browser's javascript is disabled?

Tags: php, javascript

I put some validation to check input data is valid or not. this checking is done by javascript. however, when I disabled my browser's javascript that validation is not working.

Comment: Then use ServerSide validation always...

Comment: Simple use server side validation

Comment: How are you validating it now?

Comment: Read [this](http://web.securityinnovation.com/appsec-weekly/blog/bid/67936/Do-Not-Rely-on-Client-Side-Validation) why

Comment: Always validate the inputs in the `PHP` code that is processing the form submission, regardless of any JavaScript validation.

Comment: You should always get the server to validate the data even if Javascript is enabled. Javascript is there just to make the users experience more responsive and pleasant. At the even of the day the server need to take care of the information that it feeds into the database and use.

Comment: Just as an important security note. You should have always been validating form data whether you're sure that JavaScript is enabled or not..

Comment: I want to validate data before form submission, so I used keyEvents of javascript. That is the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side validation is the best option always. However if Server Side Validation is out of scope, you could leverage HTML5 Form validation.

> HTML5 also offers validation of web addresses entered into  fields, and numbers in  fields. The
>   validation of numbers even takes into account the min and max
>   attributes, so browsers will not let you submit the form if you enter
>   a number that is too large.

If you don't want to validate a Form using HTMl5 simple use `novalidate` atribute

```
<form novalidate>
  <input type="email" id="addr">
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Comment: Never rely on client-side validation.

Answer (score 2):

You should always validate the data on the server side (PHP there), even if the javascript is enabled.

With HTML5 you can add the `required` attribute :

```
<input type="text" required="true" />
```

Comment: BUT! Always check through PHP, I can edit your HTML...

Comment: Yes ofc, it's writen black on white...

Comment: Sure? Hmm didn't see it... Then again, can't be said too often.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it via PHP or PERL after submitting form (serversided).
You should do this everytime, additional to javascript check

Check this out http://buildinternet.com/2008/12/how-to-validate-a-form-complete-with-error-messages-using-php-part-1/